# Self-signed certificate installation on client side

Tags: c++, openssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

Let's imagine we have the server with self-signed certificate and the client which want to connect to the server. Client don't have the certificate from server installed on it's store.

Is it correct that client can fetch the certificate from server, add it to it's own certificate store (after user confirmation) and have secured connection?

I am asking because I don't want to spread the sertificate to all clients by some way.
I just want them to be able to download certificate from server during first connection attempt and use it, if user confirm it's trustable.

Comment: How does the user confirm that it's trustable the first time?

Comment: What you are asking for is basically impossible. CA-signed certificate chains are what makes a user capable of confirming that it's trustable without having to spread the certificate. That's literally all they do. If you can do that, then it's not a self-signed certificate anymore. It's just a regular chained certificate.